# How to ping/connect to a KVM on another machine in the same lan?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ping

I have 2 machines in my cluster, say `M1` and `M2`. I have one machine installed with a VM (brought up by `virt-install`), say `VM` on `M2`.

My `M2` can ping the IP address of `VM`. My `M1` and `M2` can also ping each other.

But `M1` cannot reach out to `VM`. What additional setup do I need to let `M1` able to talk to `VM`? Like bridges or routers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you install the Guest using default settings, the Guest gets its IP subnet from the VBOX internal DHCP server.   Does that help?

Comment: I'm not sure what VBOX is in this scenario. I'm using libvirt.

Comment: I looked here:    https://documentation.suse.com/smart/virtualization-cloud/html/manage-vm-on-commandline/index.html#:~:text=libvirt%20allows%20remote%20management%20of,line%20to%20write%20XML%20configurations.   and libvirt is a collection of apps   ..   You would need to look in these Apps to see how Guests get IP addresses.   (Bridged, NAT  in most cases).  Not enough here to help you.   I use VMware and Hyper-V and pinging / connecting to machines is straightforward.

Comment: @itsjc - [Edit] your question to make that clear.